# How to route an url to an specific method of a class Django and DRF

Tags: python, django, routes, django-rest-framework, pycharm

I am very new in the python world and now I building an application with Django 1.8 with the Rest Framework and I want to create a class view to DRY my code.

For example I want to have a class view for the students in my system

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status


class SnippetList(APIView):
    def getWorstStudents(self, request, format=None):
        # Logic here
```

How can I assign a specified URL in **urls.py** to hit this method?

And also I have implemented **REST framework JWT Auth**
http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/ for token auth.

How can I restrict the access to allow only authenticated users can access to this url?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Use [routers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#routers) with [viewsets](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/).

First, subclass your view from `ModelViewSet` instead of from `APIView`. Second, use the `@list_route` decorator in your `getWorstStudents` method. Third, tie everything up in your `urls.py` with a router.

It should look like (I have not tested the code):

## views.py

```
class StudentsViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    @list_route(methods=['get'], permission_classes=(IsAuthenticated,))  # you can define who can access this view here
    def getWorstStudents(self, request, format=None):
        # Logic here

# routers.py
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'students', views.StudentsViewSet, base_name='student')

# urls.py
import .routers import router
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
]
```

The router will generate a view with the name `student-getWorstStudents` accessible from the `students/getWorstStudents` url.

Answer (score 1):

You can set urls like any other Django app, [documented here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#example)

```
# urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url
from somewhere import SnippetList

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^your/url/$', SnippetList.as_view()),
]
```

About DRY with your method, you can define the method you want to response to, and call the `getWorstStudents` (btw by convention I would call it get_worst_students). Let's say you want to response the `post` method:

```
# views.py

from rest_framework.response import Response

def getWorstStudents(params)

class SnippetList(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # call getWorstStudents method here and response a Response Object
```

You can define `getWorstStudents` inside `SnippetList` class or in other file to import wherever you need it.

Finally, about authentication, DRF provides classes for this, [documented here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/).

From docs, you need define this in your `settings.py` file:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    )
}
```

And use it in your views:

```
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class ExampleView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        content = {
            'user': unicode(request.user),  # `django.contrib.auth.User` instance.
            'auth': unicode(request.auth),  # None
        }
        return Response(content)
```

You can also define your own authentication class and set it in `authentication_classes` tuple. [Custom authentication classes documented here.](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#custom-authentication)

Comment: Hi. Thank for your answer I have a question what happen if I want to handle more than one post route, example: 

set_note_of_student() and set_email_of_student() How can I assign a specific route to each of this methods? Thank you again.

Comment: You can response to the standard HTTP methods: `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, etc. Inside this methos you can call any other method you want before return the Response. I understand your question, you can use [routers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#routers) with ViewSets.